# Centered alignment of image element within SVG document

Tags: image, svg, alignment, aspect-ratio

I am trying to achieve several graphic stretch modes for an image element within a SVG document.
It has to be noted that the solution shall work without JavaScript and CSS and I have no upfront knowledge about the image's dimensions (just about space where the image has to be placed).

For Uniform, UniformToFill and Fill this is really no problem. The samples below are placing an image onto an area of 400x100 pixels:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">

<!-- GraphicStretchMode: UniformToFill -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="10" y="10" width="400" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="https://thereforeigeek.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/nessy.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="100" fill="transparent" stroke="#630" stroke-width="5px"/>
</svg>

<!-- GraphicStretchMode: Fill -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  x="10" y="130"  width="400" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="https://thereforeigeek.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/nessy.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="100" fill="transparent" stroke="#630" stroke-width="5px"/>
</svg>

<!-- GraphicStretchMode: Uniform -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  x="10" y="250" width="400" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="https://thereforeigeek.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/nessy.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="100" fill="transparent" stroke="#630" stroke-width="5px"/>
</svg>

</svg>
```

Nevertheless, I don't get stretch mode None (unscaled, unstretched, in original size but centered!) done. (And this was what I initially assumed to be the most simple case)

Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of "stretch mode None" is not possible to achieve in SVG unless you know the natural size of the image you are using (ie 630 x 474 in this case).

"100%" relates to the size of the SVG, not the size of the source image you are using.

**Update**

If you do set the image dimensions to the intrinsic size of the image (to have it display at 1:1), then the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute no longer applies. That's because you are no longer scaling the image to a different size from its intrinsic size.

You need to use another method to reposition it so it is centred. The most obvious way is using `x` and `y`.  The offsets in this case will be.

```
x = (630 - 400) / 2 = 115
y = (474 - 100) / 2 = 187
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">

<!-- GraphicStretchMode: None -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  x="10" y="10" width="400" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="https://thereforeigeek.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/nessy.jpg" height="474" width="630" x="-115" y="-187"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="100" fill="transparent" stroke="#630" stroke-width="5px"/>
</svg>

</svg>
```

Comment: I was aware that the 100% in my three modes above relate to the size of the parent SVG element - that was by intention to achieve the stretch modes. ;-)
Was just wondering if there is really no way to get stretch mode none centered. Leaving away width and height on the image does indeed allow an unscaled (stretch mode none) pic, BUT it is not centered but always on the top left. So I asked myself if some transformation or viewbox might help.

Comment: Thanks Paul, seems to be the only solution to get it centered. Unfortunately I have no chance regarding the requirement for "no upfront knowledge about the image's dimensions". :(

Comment: And you aren't able to use Javascript either (to read the image dimensions and update the SVG)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is meant to be used in a self-contained template that is not allowed to contain code.